# Bold search term in search results

Tags: php, mysql, search

When users search my database, I'd like the search term to bold itself in the results.  I can't seem to find a tutorial or explanation that can be implemented easily into my existing code.  I'm a PHP newbie, so please be patient.  So, what I'd like is if someone searches "blue" then the results would display something similar to this:

Searched term: 
**Blue**

Results:
1 - **Blue** - Horse - Black Body Color - Red Eyes
2 - Jimmy - Horse - **Blue** Body Color - Black Eyes

So on and so forth.

Here is my search.php page code:

```
<?php
$query = $_GET['query']; 
// gets value sent over search form

$min_length = 3;
// you can set minimum length of the query if you want

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal     minimum length then

$query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
// changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

$query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
// makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM characters
    WHERE (`name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`player` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`dam` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`sire` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`status` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

// * means that it selects all fields, you can also write: `id`, `title`, `text`
// articles is the name of our table

// '%$query%' is what we're looking for, % means anything, for example if $query is Hello
// it will match "hello", "Hello man", "gogohello", if you want exact match use `title`='$query'
// or if you want to match just full word so "gogohello" is out use '% $query %' ...OR ... '$query %' ... OR ... '% $query'

if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
    // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

        echo "Searched term:<br>";
echo "<b>" . $query . "</b>";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "Results:<br>";
foreach($results as $index => $resultArray) {
$resultString = $index+1 . " - ";
foreach($resultArray as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($value, $query) !== FALSE) { // strpos returns a value between 0 and n if the string is found; if it's NOT found, it returns FALSE - due to PHP's veeeerry loose typing, we need to use !== rather than simply !=, because otherwise 0 will return **as** FALSE
        $resultString .= "<b>" . $value . "</b>";
    } else {
        $resultString .= $value;
    }
    $resultString .= " - ";
}
echo substr($resultString, 0, -3) . "<br>"; // We're chopping off the last " - "
}
    }

}
else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
    echo "No results found.";
}

}
else{ // if query length is less than minimum
echo "Search term is invalid.  Minumum search length is: ".$min_length;
}
?>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

**After using one of the suggestions below, I get tons of this error:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home3/hunstami/public_html/characters/search.php on line 63
1**

**I'm guessing I just tried to implement this incorrectly into my code, but like I said above, I'm completely new at this.**

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head there are two methods for doing this.  Both involve keeping the html you plan to write to the screen in a variable for a little while.

**Method A - Bold the string while looping through the results set**

```
// In while loop
row = "#".$results['id']." - ";

if $results['name'] == $query {
 row = row."<strong>".$query."</strong>";
else {
 row = row.$query;
}

row = row." - ".$results['breed']." - ".$results['gender'] // SNIP, use the rest like you use it now
```

**Method B - Return a string and do a find and replace for the search term**

```
html = "";

// while loop
  html = html."#".$results['id']." - ".$results['name']." - ".$results['breed']." - ".$results['gender']." - ".$results['sire']." x ".$results['dam']." - ".$results['genetics']." - ".$results['body']." Base - ".$results['mane']." Mane - ".$results['tail']." Tail - ".$results['eye']." Eyes - ".$results['markings']." - Born: ".$results['birthdate']." - ".$results['bodytype']." Body Type - ".$results['traits']." - ".$results['defects']." - ".$results['extras']." - Achievements: ".$results['achievements']." - Status: ".$results['status']." - Notes: ".$results['notes']." - Played by ".$results['player']."<br><br>";

// end while

html = str_replace(html, $query, "<strong>".$query."</strong>");

echo html;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
echo "Searched term:<br>";
echo "<b>" . $query . "</b>";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "Results:<br>";
foreach($results as $index => $resultArray) {
    $resultString = $index+1 . " - ";
    foreach($resultArray as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($value, $query) !== FALSE) { // strpos returns a value between 0 and n if the string is found; if it's NOT found, it returns FALSE - due to PHP's veeeerry loose typing, we need to use !== rather than simply !=, because otherwise 0 will return **as** FALSE
            $resultString .= "<b>" . $value . "</b>";
        } else {
            $resultString .= $value;
        }
        $resultString .= " - ";
    }
    echo substr($resultString, 0, -3) . "<br>"; // We're chopping off the last " - "
}
```

I don't know whether it's okay to include this type of thing in an answer to a question, but I'd also suggest replacing your queries with PDO (which is pretty easy, actually, but far more secure than the simple mysql_query()-type functions - which leave you more open to SQL injection attacks) - something like this:

Well, the first thing I'd suggest is to change over your database calls to PDO. A quick Google search for something like "PHP PDO tutorial" will find you a guide, but ultimately it's not much more complicated than simple mysql_query()s - but it's more secure.

In this case, I would do something like:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=YOUR HOST; dbname=YOUR DATABASE', 'YOUR USERNAME', 'YOUR PASSWORD');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM CHARACTERS WHERE (name LIKE :query) OR (player LIKE :query) OR (dam LIKE :query) OR (sire LIKE :query) OR (status LIKE :query);")
    $stmt->execute([
        "query" => "%" . $query . "%"; // This binds ":query" to the value that you give it. It takes an array.
    ]);
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

It's also, I think, a bit cleaner. :)

Comment: I tried your first suggestion and it returns a bunch of errors - I updated my original post above to reflect what I did to the code to get these errors.  Thank you for your help.